# Vertically centered div go out of the background

Tags: css

I  centered a div vertically with CSS and it works great. But I have a background and when I resize browser the text go out the background.

[image]

```
.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    background: rgba(51,51,51,.5);
}


.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 50%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5t9asdc1/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.wrapper` is `div`, so it already has `width: 100%` (because div has `display: block`, and we know that all blocks are full width elements). `.wrapper { height: 100%; }` means that it will inherit the full height of its parent (in this case it is `body`, `body` inherit height of its parent - `html` - so you get the viewport height); So we can remove all `.wrapper` styles. And simply add `background: rgba(51,51,51,.5);` to `.outer`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {

}

.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(51,51,51,.5);
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="inner">
            
                <h1>The Content</h1>
                
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/5t9asdc1/3/
you should use `min-height` and delete here `position: absolute;`

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the `//` probably shouldn't be used for demonstration, as it isn't 'copyable' Use `/**/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**[Jsfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5t9asdc1/4/)**

No need to use `position:absolute` in `.outer` and specifying height in `.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper{
/* height:100%; remove this-**/
width: 100%;    
background: rgba(51,51,51,.5);
}
.outer {
display: table;
/* position: absolute; remove this-**/
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```